# How to absorb other stars from my system?

Tags: solar-2

I have a hexinary star system and I want to combine the other stars (or some of them) into my main one. How do I do that?

Comment: IIRC, it works the same way as eating up your planets. But I currently don't have it installed to test.

Comment: You cannot highlight a star and press the Y button to eat the selected star like you can with a planet. Similarly, pressing the B button when you have only stars will not consume the smallest star. I also don't know how to combine stars, but I can verify the methods used to consume planets do not work.

Comment: I ended up ramming other solar systems until I only had my largest star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot absorb stars the same way that you absorb planets. Asteroids can absorb other asteroids, but planets cannot absorb other planets, and stars cannot absorb other stars.

If you just want to get rid of the other stars in your system, your technique of ramming other solar systems until you only have your largest star is the best choice.